# how don't submit form if validation not passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I have wrote a small code snippet:

html:

```
<label for="searchTextField">Please Insert an address:</label>
<br>
<form id = "formId" action="google.com">
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
    <input type="submit" value="is valid" id="submitId">
<form>
```

js:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
$("#formId").submit(function(e){
    return editTerminal(e);
});
function editTerminal(id, e) {
            function setPosition(){
                console.log("logic");            
            };
            return codeEditAddress(setPosition,e);
}      

 function codeEditAddress( callback, e) {
        var address = document.getElementById('searchTextField').value;
        var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //should be submit
                alert('good address');
            } else {
                //should NOT be submit
                alert('wrong address');
                e.preventDefault();

            }
    });
 }
```

### [jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SDPHm/689/)

Now my form submits anyway.
I want to achieve that it not submits if shows `wrong address` message.

Please, help to modify code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling your function

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e){
return editTerminal(e); });
```

on form submit you should replace your submit input by a button and launch your function on it's onclick event.
Then if the adress is valid submit the form manually :

```
$("#formId").submit();
```

S.P

Comment: They problem with this is that hitting enter on a form field also submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your geocode function is asynchronous. Anything you do in it will not effect the event processing.

I would just always return false for the submit event

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e){
    editTerminal(e);
    return false;
});
```

And do a pure js form submit for a good address to bypass the submit listener:

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pmou2zx/1